# Which .Net Standard version supports which Android versions?

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.android, portable-class-library, .net-standard

I want to convert a Xamarin PCL project to .Net Standard.

My question is, what versions of Android will that support? My current project supports Android 4. Will .Net Standard be able to support it? Does it depend on the .Net Standard version?

I've seen [this table](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/net-standard) but it only tells me the "Xamarin" version supported, and I don't understand the connection between that and the Android version. Is .Net Standard unrelated to the Android version (somewhat like the C# version is separate from the .Net version) or is .Net Standard tied to specific versions of Android (among the other framework it supports)?

Comment: android does not support .net out of the box. that's where xamarian or mono comes in. you will have to read their documentation to indicate which versions of android are supported.

Comment: @DanielA.White .Net Standard is not .Net. From the link in the question: `.NET Standard is the replacement for Portable Class Libraries (PCL).`. It's specifically created in order to write code that works everywhere*. (* Some restrictions apply :)

Comment: oh i know that but the specific implementation is up to the xamarin folks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The connection is between the **Version of Xamarin.Android**, not the Android Version / API level. This means that as long as you are using the version of Xamarin.Android or greater in your local installation, you will support .NET Standard.

- **.NET Standard 1.0-1.6** has been supported in Xamarin.Android since Xamarin.Android 7.0.

https://developer.xamarin.com/releases/android/xamarin.android_7/xamarin.android_7.0/ *(Sorry there is no note in these release notes as they recently were revamped)*

- **.NET Standard 2.0** has been supported in Xamarin.Android since Xamarin.Android 8.0.

https://developer.xamarin.com/releases/android/xamarin.android_8/xamarin.android_8.0/#.NET_Standard_2.0_Support

Comment: Thanks again! Do I understand correctly that just as I can develop **for older versions of Android** using the latest Android SDK, I will be able to develop **for those older versions** using .Net Standard? (assuming for example, that I'm using Xamarin.Android 8.0 and .Net Standard 2.0)

Comment: As mentioned in the earlier question you had, there should be no reason to develop for older versions of Android. You should be setting your `compileSdkVersion` to the latest and set your `minSdkVersion` to the lowest version of Android you need to support.

Comment: By "developing for older versions" I _mean_ `minSdkVersion`. I want the app to run on old versions.