# Multi-platform development: use recent Visual Studio with older version of Android

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android, visual-studio-2019, .net-standard

[update] I finally was able to deploy our app on 4.2 using the latest toolchain. I get an error. See below after the original text.

We are looking for a long term solution to keep using recent version of Visual Studio (2019 at the time of this post) while keeping developping for old Android platforms (prior to 4.4).

Xamarin@Microsoft dropped support for Android previous to 4.4 in the Xamarin.Android release 9.2, but we cannot drop the support for our product. 
Until now we keep using VS2017 for our specific android development, but the gap between VS2019 and VS2017 development environment is increasing and this is adding an increasing overhead on our day-to-day development.

Our projects are developped using a mostly common code base for a software deployed on PC, but part of this code is also part of an Android application that can run on specific devices.
For PC development which is our main activity, we want as much as possible to be able to code using the latest .NET standard and latest tools.

The Android version is an industrial software very specific to the hardware it is used on, and we cannot expect the Android OS to be updated, so we are stuck with a minimal Android version support of 4.2.2.

I already searched on SO and other forums, but didn't find any "good" long-term solution.
For information here are some of the good information I found related to this topic:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/release-notes/9/9.2

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/app-fundamentals/android-api-levels?tabs=windows

[Which .Net Standard version supports which Android versions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48214401/which-net-standard-version-supports-which-android-versions)

https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-android/blob/master/Documentation/guides/messages/xa4216.md

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/net-standard

Currently I think what we can do is:

1) Mainly use .NET standard libraries for the common parts of our code

2) Having very few assemblies directly using Xamarin.Android, typically only for the UI part.

Note that this is close to what we are already doing now (except that we could port more of our assemblies to .NET Standard I think).

However since we target API level 4.4 and use the application on 4.2, we may call some APIs that are not supported in 4.2, or even worse, APIs that are supported but buggy because the new Xamarin/Mono runtime does not support old Android versions. This is especially true since there is the warning XA4216: even if we can deploy and run on an older android because the manifest allows it, we cannot ensure that the OS provides all the necessary features used by the mono runtime.
At the moment the warning XA4216 is for version 4.0.3, but we see the day coming when we update VS2019 and get this warning for Android 4.2.

So is there a better solution than:

1) Keep the old VS2017/old Xamarin.Android build environment and block our day-to-day productivity to keep ensuring full compatibility with Android 4.2

2) Update our build and development environment fully to VS2019 with latest Xamarin and pray that the implementation is not bugged on older OS.

I would like to be able to go with 2 and have some insurance that everything will work fine, without having to retest the whole application each time there is an update of visual studio.
What do you think? 
To ensure application stability, are we stuck with the old build system (VS2017 + old Xamarin.Android), or is it a "safe" risk to upgrade to VS2019 with latest Xamarin?

Thanks in advance for any good advice on this topic.

PS:
I pushed with solution 2: "Update our build and development environment fully to VS2019 with latest Xamarin and pray that the implementation is not bugged on older OS." to do the test locally on my PC at first.
After making necessary changes in our app so that it builds with VS2019 & latest Xamarin, I deployed to test on our Android 4.2.2 device (took me 1 whole day to fix the build errors...). I get the following error and app freezes:
W/libc    ( 9196): protoent* getprotobyname(char const*)(3) is not implemented on Android.

Maybe praying was not enough... any ideas?

Comment: Are you confusing `minSdkVersion` vs `targetSdkVersion`? As stated in Xamarin's doc: **Note that applications built against a target framework version of Android 4.4 (API level 19) or higher can still be deployed and run successfully on devices that are using Android 4.3 (API level 18) or lower.** You of course have to ensure (either through testing and|or runtime checks) that the APIs that you are calling are available on the API-level that the app is actually running on.

Comment: No I am not confusing both, as I pointed out I already read the documentation. My problem is more that although we can choose "minSdkVersion=v4.0.3" for example, if we do this we get the warning XA4216. This warning tells us that android versions priori to 4.1 are not supported anymore.
So far so good since we use 4.2.2, but what about the future? This does look to be an acceptable short term solution, but I doubt that this backward compatibility was correctly tested, so we would still need to perform full application test when upgrading Visual Studio for our build system.

Comment: But thanks for your comment anyway.

Comment: For information, here is the kind of issue I expect to encounter if using our app on Android prior to 4.1:
https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/166019/app-crashes-immediately-at-startup-on-device-below-api-16-is-api-15-not-supported-any-more
It was fixed for Android 4.1 but I don't think it works in previous versions... 
And so for me it is a lie to say that simply selecting minSdkVersion makes our app backward compatible. Maybe we could install it, but I doubt it would run properly on devices prior to 4.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go with option 2 & update your build and development environment fully to VS2019 with latest Xamarin! The implementation should not bug any older OS.

Even if it does add bugs, just test your code in QA. As for production, you can place good crash analytics on your app, and you ll be able to catch, report and fix any  bugs.

For the most part, on Android the number of users using below Android 4.4 is less than 0.001% of all users. At that point, it makes more sense to implement Accessibility in your app, since that affects 1000x more users.

Comment: Thanks for sharing your opinion.


[`For the most part, on Android the number of users using below Android 4.4 is less than 0.001% of all users. At that point, it makes more sense to implement Accessibility in your app, since that affects 1000x more users.`]


Actually I was saying it in the original post, but our app is used on industrial hardware for which the OS version cannot be upgraded. So in summary for our case this represents 100% of our users.

I know this is a difficult topic, so if there is no better answer I will accept this as an answer in a few days.

Comment: Hello again,
I tried going with solution 2 and upgrade the build environment. I made the necessary changes so that the project could build, but in the end when I run the app on our older device we get the following error and freeze:
protoent* getprotobyname(char const*)(3) is not implemented on Android

This is typically for this kind of issue that I think Xamarin dropped support for older platforms, so it looks like there is no solution for our needs.

If nothing works we will keep the old build environment.

Still I mark this as the accepted answer as there is  no better one.

Comment: Don’t give up! Check out this @Rigolf https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/74083/httpclient-protoent-getprotobyname-char-const-3-is-not-implemented-on-android

Comment: Hi, thanks for your feedback. Just to give an update, the freeze was due to a bad overloading in the code fixed for the change of API level. By fixing that the app startsup but I get strange bugs (some UI stuff that should fade out after some time just stay displayed, etc.). I'll post another comment if there is some news on this topic.